# Automate Int and Character Sequence in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

How do I generate a number and character sequence in Java from a range of A-F and 1-11, to mimic a airplane seating system. For Example, to create an array {1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,2A,2B etc...}.

I've tried doing this, but it doesn't quite do what I'd like it to:

```
char[][] seats = new char[5][6]; // 30 seats

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){    
            seats[i][0] = 'A';
            seats[i][1] = 'B';
            seats[i][2] = 'C';
            seats[i][3] = 'D';
            seats[i][4] = 'E';
            seats[i][5] = 'F';         
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

To generate a number and character sequence in Java from a range of `A-F` and `1-11`, you can use this function `generateAirplaneSeats` which takes the number of rows and the number of airplane seats per row as method parameters, and then returns an array of strings representing airplane seats:

```
public static String[] generateAirplaneSeats(final int numberRows, final int numberSeatsPerRow) {
        String[] airplaneSeats = new String[numberRows * numberSeatsPerRow];

        for(int row = 1; row <= numberRows; row++) {
            for(int seat = 0; seat < numberSeatsPerRow; seat++) {
                char airplaneSeatLetter = getAirplaneSeatLetter(seat);
                String airplaneSeatNumber = getAirplaneSeatNumber(row, airplaneSeatLetter);
                airplaneSeats[(row - 1) * numberSeatsPerRow + seat] = airplaneSeatNumber;
            }
        }

        return airplaneSeats;
    }
```

Where the function `getAirplaneSeatLetter` takes a airplane seat index as a method parameter and then returns the appropriate airplane seat letter.

For example, if the seat index is `0`, it means that it corresponds to the first seat in a row, which would be seat `A`. Therefore, the function `getAirplaneSeatLetter(0)` would return the character `A`.

```
    public static char getAirplaneSeatLetter(final int seatIndex) {
        return (char) ('A' + seatIndex);
    }
```

Where the function`getAirplaneSeatNumber` takes a row number and a airplane seat letter as method parameters and then returns the appropriate airplane seat number.

For example, if the row number is `1` and the airplane seat letter is `A`, that corresponds to the first seat in the first row, which would be seat `1A`. Therefore, the function `getAirplaneSeatNumber(1, 'A')` would return the string `1A`.

```
    public static String getAirplaneSeatNumber(final int row, final char airplaneSeatLetter) {
        return row + String.valueOf(airplaneSeatLetter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each seat is identified by more than one character, so use a `String` array instead. Then, you can use a nested for loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++)
        seats[i][j] = i + 1 + String.valueOf((char)(j + 'A'));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(seats));
// [[1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F], [2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E, 2F], [3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, 3E, 3F], [4A, 4B, 4C, 4D, 4E, 4F], [5A, 5B, 5C, 5D, 5E, 5F]]
```